# AFNetworking issues

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, afnetworking

I have a question regarding AFNetworking..:

1. I'm setting cell's image with `setImageWithURL:` but found out that requests are sent in some random order, i.e. i'm setting images for cells #1,2,3,4 and request for image #3 will be sent at first.
2. same scenario, I've noticed that sometimes two connections are opened (often one of them has "Client closed connection" status before receiving entire response, but now always).

Is there an explanation for such behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html#//api/name/setImageWithURL%3a) for this method, all this processing is done asynchronously. So some requests may start or finish at different times. Depending on the image's file size or the servers latency they may start or finish at different times.

If you wanted to set the images in order you could hold back on setting the cell's image until the previous cell was finished within the success block of `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` described [here](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html#//api/name/setImageWithURLRequest%3aplaceholderImage%3asuccess%3afailure%3a).

You could also manipulate AFHTTPClient and AFImageResquestOperation to only download one image at a time with NSOperationQueue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` method.